# Capture the numbers in this regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
{{1090872, "A"}, {4281, "AA"}, {1332552, "AAACU"}, {1287145, "AABB"}}
```

How can I write a regex to capture the numbers. I know that I can capture the letters with: "(.*?)"

Comment: `re.findall(r'\b\d+(?=,)', s)`

Comment: `I know that I can capture the letters with: "(.*?)"` You can capture the numbers like that too.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have number in quotes, then answer is

```py
import re
str = '{{1090872, "A"}, {4281, "AA"}, {1332552, "AAACU"}, {1287145, "AABB"}}'
re.findall(r'\d+', str)
['1090872', '4281', '1332552', '1287145']
```

otherwise you can try

```py
re.findall(r'[{},](\d+)[{},]', str)
```